# Using Async Await vb.net 4.5.2

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous

Having some trouble using the Await in my code. I get the following error message;
'Await' requires that the type 'String' have a suitable GetAwaiter method.

```
Async Function TestAsync() As Task(Of String)
    Dim test As String = Await FunctionThatReturnsString(x, y, z)
    Return test
```

Any help is much appreciated. ( I checked for the reference system.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll and couldn't seem to find it to include/add it_

Comment: What is `FunctionThatReturnsString`? If it actually returns just a `String`, why are you using `Await` with it?

Comment: `FunctionThatReturnsString` should return `Task<string>`

Comment: @Ryan it calls a database in the function and returns a string at the end

Comment: Please include its definition in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should always stick on the "async all the way" recommendation, which means that everything in call chain should be async, including FunctionThatReturnsString. But you can call it synchronously like this:

```
Async Function TestAsync() As Task(Of String)
  Dim result As String = Nothing
  Dim worker As New Task(Sub()
                           result = FunctionThatReturnsString(1, 2, 3)
                         End Sub)
  worker.Start()
  worker.Wait()
  Return result
End Function

Function FunctionThatReturnsString(x, y, z) As String
  Return Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
End Function
```